# SQLite WHERE IN for multiple columns and passing list as arguments

Tags: sql, sqlite, flask

I know that there many questions on this topic but I can't find one that directly solve my problems.

Right now I am trying to build a webapp in Flask and SQLite and I have a table with columns: Date, Country and Name and I'm doing a request form on these data

```
country = request.form.getlist('country')
name = request.form.getlist('name')

str_from_date = request.form.get('from_date')
str_to_date = request.form.get('to_date')
from_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str_from_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
to_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str_to_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then I want to select from the table data that fits these criteria so

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE country_col IN {country}
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name_col IN {name}
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(date_col) >= {from_date} AND date(date_col) <= {to_date}
```

But all in one sql statement and I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: You need one `SELECT` that uses `AND`, like `WHERE country_col IN country AND name_col IN`.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you! And how do I input the data into it? I tried .format() but it didn't really work

Comment: Your question here was about writing the SQL that would do it in one SELECT instead of three. If you now have a new question, use the *Ask Question* button to create a new post and ask it there.